# Installing module in Odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo

So I've recently transitioned from version 7 to 8. Was just trying to create a basic module with the new api and kept getting the same error regardless any changes I made.

I have this:

```
from openerp import models, fields


class IncomingDeliveryFollowup(models.Model):
    _name = 'xx.incoming.delivery.followup'

    _columns = {
        'xx_price_unit': fields.Float(string='Unit Price', required=True),
    }
```

And I keep getting:

```
AttributeError: to_field
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use

```
_columns = {
    'xx_price_unit': fields.Float(string='Unit Price', required=True),
}
```

Instead use

```
xx_price_unit =  fields.Float(string='Unit Price', required=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `models.Model` of the new Odoo API, you should define your model as follows

```
from openerp import models, fields

class IncomingDeliveryFollowup(models.Model):
    _name = 'xx.incoming.delivery.followup'

    xx_price_unit = fields.Float(string='Unit Price', required=True)
```

Reference:

- [ORM API - Odoo 8.0 Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html)